# Total coins bought drop significantly after reaching my wallet

Tags: bsc, pancakeswap

Please let me know if this is not the right place to ask this, just can't figure out at all what's going on here.

Chain: BSC
The coin in question : 0xaba5da7b9da3c62f5bc625e471305b43ad244f43

The issue:
I am running a bot for testing purposes and making small transactions (swaps) on certain coins. This coin, for $2(in WBNB) at the time of the swap gave me a total of 598,301.67 coins (Hash: 0x2a607a8354cb627d408d46177aabdbe18f26a74cd6a48414fdfb1de073a1fea9). But it seems that immediately after, once I do balance inquiry I only actually have a very small percentage of that number in my wallet.

So as I sell a percentage of those coins, like in this transaction (Hash: 0x38f6fca1fd911cb6355b253c235774a33389976eb9a80cb549ab8ff6e9911428), which is supposed to be 30% of total holdings. I only sell a very small number of coins compared to the amount bought. Based on the other transactions visible on Dextools (https://www.dextools.io/app/bsc/pair-explorer/0xe5e141a40b43d4d856ba26918f14fbcc16ba682c), no-one seems to having this problem, unless the majority of those transactions are "fake".

Anyone have any Idea whats going on here?

Comment: It is a scam token, the owner can override any balance at any time, look at the function `RewardToken` of the contract.

Comment: I figured the culprit was there, wanted to make sure though. Thank you :)